# Android: RNAppAuth.authorize got 14 arguments, expected 15

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

The error code `RNAppAuth.authorize got 14 arguments, expected 15` is appearing in Firebase after I just released a new version of my app. This error is preventing some of my users from entering the app. For them, it is crashing on open.

I've tested my app locally on an android emulator and can open it/use it no problem.

Does anyone know what this error means/how I can approach a solution?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.